# Spark Filter function with map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am a newbiee to spark and am having issues trying to filter a map.
i am trying to remove teh header from the .csv file and trying to filer out certain records. but for some reason my filter condition is
not working .

```
val dataWithHeader = sc.textFile("/user/skv/airlines.csv")  
val headerAndRows = dataWithHeader.map(x => x.split(",").map(_.trim)
val Header = headerAndRows.first    
val data = headerAndRows.filter(_(0) != Header(0))

val maps = data.map( x => Header.zip(x).toMap)       
 //result looks like //res0:     
 // Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] =     
 // Array(Map(Code -> "19031", Description -> "Mackey International Inc.: MAC"),
 //       Map(Code -> "19032", Description -> "Munz Northern Airlines Inc.: XY"), 
 //now when i am trying to filter the map with the below condition the filter is not working ?

val result = maps.filter(x => x("Code") != "19031")
```

airlines.csv looks like

```
 Code,Description
"19031","Mackey International Inc.: MAC"
"19032","Munz Northern Airlines Inc.: XY"
"19033","Cochise Airlines Inc.: COC"   
"19034","Golden Gate Airlines Inc.: GSA"  
"19035","Aeromech Inc.: RZZ" 
"19036","Golden West Airlines Co.: GLW"  
"19037","Puerto Rico Intl Airlines: PRN"  
"19038","Air America Inc.: STZ"  
"19039","Swift Aire Lines Inc.: SWT"
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a pair of double quotes too much (because you read double quotes from your csv).

try replacing

```
val headerAndRows = dataWithHeader.map(x => x.split(",").map(_.trim)
```

with

```
val headerAndRows = dataWithHeader.map(x => x.split(",").map(_.trim.replace("\"", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `double quote` in your data. You can make you work done in two ways :

> 1. By removing double quote from data by replacing double quote ( as answered by `Raphael Roth` )
> 2. By comparing your values with double quotes like this

```
 val result = maps.filter(x => { 
      x("Code") != "\"19031\""
    })
```

Comment: @satish_venu Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.